# Angular.JS app.controller not working in html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having problems getting app.controller "TestCtrl" to work in the HTML page. I think there might be some sort of interruption with the app.controllers, when I do try the app controller by itself it will work. However, when I add additional controllers, they do not work accordingly. Can any1 help me figure out the problem and explain to me what I did wrong?

```js
(function(){
var app = angular.module('AVS', []);
  
  app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){
  var tabClasses;
  
  function initTabs() {
    tabClasses = ["","","",""];
  }
  
  $scope.getTabClass = function (tabNum) {
    return tabClasses[tabNum];
  };
  
  $scope.getTabPaneClass = function (tabNum) {
    return "tab-pane " + tabClasses[tabNum];
  }
  
  $scope.setActiveTab = function (tabNum) {
    initTabs();
    tabClasses[tabNum] = "active";
  };
  
  $scope.tab1 = " 555dsadsa";
  $scope.tab2 = "dsadasa ";
  $scope.tab3 = "dsadas ";
  $scope.tab4 = "dsadsa ";
  
  //Initialize 
  initTabs();
  $scope.setActiveTab(1);
});
  

  app.controller('StoreController',function(){
    this.products = disciplines;
  });
  
  app.controller('FloorDrawings', function(){
    this.floors = drawings;
  });
  
  app.controller('GearNavigation', function(){
    this.gearnav = gnavigation;
  });
  
  app.controller('Reports', function (){
    this.reports = nameofreports;
    
  });
  
  app.controller('DrawingSelection', function (){
    this.selection = drawselect;
  });
  
  
  var disciplines = [
        {name:'Link1',link:'#', status: 'active-link'},
        {name:'Link2 ',link:'#', status: 'active-link'},
        {name:'Link3 ',link:'#', status: 'active-link'},
        {name:'Link', link:'#', status: 'inactive-link disabled'},
        {name:'Link', link:'#', status: 'active-link'},
        {name:'Link', link: '#', status: 'active-link'},
        {name:'Link', link: '#', status: 'inactive-link disabled'},
        {name:'Link', link: '#', status: 'active-link'},
        {name:'Link', link: '#', status: 'active-link'},
        {name:'Link', link: '#', status: 'active-link'},
        {name:'Link', link: '#', status: 'inactive-link disabled'},
        {name:'Link', link:'#', status: 'active-link'},
        {name:'Link', link:'#', status: 'active-link'},
        {name:'Link', link:'#', status: 'active-link'}
    ];
  
  var drawings = [
    {floors: 'Ground Floor', initials: 'GR', labelname: 'PDF', labelname2: 'DWF', labelname3: 'CAD', filenumber: 'file1' status:'active-link'},
    {floors: '1st Floor', initials: '01', labelname: 'PDF', labelname2: 'DWF', labelname3: 'CAD', filenumber: 'file2' status:'active-link'},
    {floors: '2nd Floor', initials: '02', labelname: 'PDF', labelname2: 'DWF', labelname3: 'CAD', filenumber: 'file3' status:'active-link'},
    {floors: '3rd Floor', initials: '03', labelname: 'PDF', labelname2: 'DWF', labelname3: 'CAD', filenumber: 'file4' status:'active-link'},
    {floors: '4th Floor', initials: '04', labelname: 'PDF', labelname2: 'DWF', labelname3: 'CAD', filenumber: 'file5' status:'active-link'},
    {floors: '5th Floor', initials: '05', labelname: 'PDF', labelname2: 'DWF', labelname3: 'CAD', filenumber: 'file6' status:'active-link'},
    {floors: '6th Floor', initials: '06', labelname: 'PDF', labelname2: 'DWF', labelname3: 'CAD', filenumber: 'file7' status:'active-link'},
    {floors: '7th Floor', initials: '07', labelname: 'PDF', labelname2: 'DWF', labelname3: 'CAD', filenumber: 'file7' status:'active-link'},
    {floors: '8th Floor', initials: '08', labelname: 'PDF', labelname2: 'DWF', labelname3: 'CAD', filenumber: 'file7' status:'active-link'},
    {floors: 'Penthouse', initials: 'PH', labelname: 'PDF', labelname2: 'DWF', labelname3: 'CAD', filenumber: 'file8' status:'active-link'}
    ]; 
  
  var gnavigation = [
    {linkname: 'Dashboard', link: '#'},
    {linkname: 'Downloads', link: '#'},
    {linkname: 'Tutorial', link: '#'},
    {linkname: 'Log-out', link: '#'}
  ];
  
  var nameofreports = [
    {reportname:'Location Query', link: '#',status:'active-link'},
    {reportname:'Cost Center Query', link: '#',status:'active-link'},
    {reportname:'Department Query', link: '#',status:'active-link'},
    {reportname:'Hatch Query', link: '#',status:'active-link'},
    {reportname:'Chart Location Query', link: '#',status:'active-link'}
  ];
  
  var drawselect = [
    {drawingname: 'Draw1', link:'#', status:'active-link'},
    {drawingname: 'Draw2', link:'#', status:'inactive-link disabled'},
    {drawingname: 'Draw3', link:'#', status:'inactive-link disabled'},
    {drawingname: 'Draw4', link:'#', status:'inactive-link disabled'}
  ];


})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="AVS">

  <head>
     <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angjs.js"></script>
  </head>

<style>
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.btn-navigation {
  width: 160px;
}

.inactive-link {
  color: gray;
}

.tab-content {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.content {
  margin:1em;
  padding:1em;
}
/*
ul, li, div {
    border:1px dotted gray;
}
*/
</style>

 <div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
      <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
               <li ng-class="getTabClass(1)" ng-click="setActiveTab(1)"><a href="#deal" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
               <li ng-class="getTabClass(2)" ng-click="setActiveTab(2)"><a href="#bond" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
               <li ng-class="getTabClass(3)" ng-click="setActiveTab(3)"><a href="#collateral" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
               <li ng-class="getTabClass(4)" ng-click="setActiveTab(4)"><a href="#rating" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
                  <div ng-class="getTabPaneClass(1)" id="deal" class="content">{{tab1}}</div>       
                  <div ng-class="getTabPaneClass(2)" id="bond" class="content">{{tab2}}</div>
                  <div ng-class="getTabPaneClass(3)" id="collateral" class="content">{{tab3}}</div>
                  <div ng-class="getTabPaneClass(4)" id="rating" class="content">{{tab4}}</div>      
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on the issue. Are you getting any errors in your console? You say when you add multiple controllers it doesn't work, yet in your HTML, I only see you using a single controller

Comment: Ronnie, I solved the problem. I didn't think console would help me out. I am fairly new to coding. Console Tab did tell me what was wrong with the script and I've corrected the error. Thanks!

Comment: The console IS your debug tool. Always have it open while you're coding because even errors or warnings that don't completely ruin the app will come back to haunt you eventually.

Comment: Try changing your controller name to all lowercase. I bet it will work.